# URL Rewrite so a domain.com is directed to domain.com/page.aspx

Tags: url-rewriting

I've been scratching my head trying to learn how to do URL rewrite.

Essentially I'm trying to achieve when user visit https://sp.company.com/ is redirected to https://sp.company.com/sites/public/default.aspx.

Can someone show me how to set up the rule in the URL Rewrite module? I find myself trying to figure out regular expression (first time) and the URL rewrite at the same time and got really lost in between.

Any expert direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN there are two type to rewrite which are:-

ASYMMETRICAL REWRITE URL

Client makes a request to https://sp.company.com/
IIS with ARR receives the request to https://sp.company.com/
ARR uses URL Rewrite to change the URL to https://sp.company.com/sites/public/default.aspx. 
The updated URL is then sent to the SharePoint web application.
**This scenario is NOT SUPPORTED.**

SYMMETRICAL REWRITE URL

Client makes a request to https://testcompany.com/sites/public/default.aspx.
IIS with ARR receives the request to https://testcompany.com/sites/public/default.aspx.
ARR uses URL Rewrite to change the URL to https://sp.company.com/sites/public/default.aspx, and then sends the new URL to the server
SharePoint receives the new URL and processes it as http://www.fabrikam.com/sites/site1
**This scenario is SUPPORTED.**

[For more info refer MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2818415/supportability-of-rewrites-and-redirects-in-sharepoint-2013-2010-and-2)

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for the reply, I got sent to a business trip right after I posted the question and has not had time to follow up on it. It sounds like sharepoint cannot support what I wanted to do, but let me read more on the MSDN site first. Thanks!